# PDF File Security Settings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

What are the Python modules/libraries which can be used to change or set the permissions of PDF file? I want to disable Print, Save, Save as, Copy for PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. The browser display PDF file as local file. So when user can see the PDF, it is already be downloaded.

You can display the file using another format, instead of browser's PDF viewer. See this site as a example: http://wenku.baidu.com/link?url=_u5cgVNlfyprUwDiVVUWWYyNh5QFdF9MeG099qZtyHZ4r4_QUV3C9JZlhIcNTTefgvjdH1gvFUuNrwyJzw8S_JlySBs5NAVc23MG5lG9Uey